# Pygame sprite not appearing

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Im trying to learn pygame and right now just trying to do a very simple task of loading a sprite image but its not appearing. Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
#Defining Sprite class
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, location):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("mario-sprite.jpg"),(50,30))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        print(self.rect)
        self.rect.x = location[0]
        self.rect.y = location[1]
        
pygame.init()
# Set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 650])
print(screen)
screen.fill((250,250,250))
bg = pygame.image.load('bk_cloud.jpg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1000, 650))
accesor = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
tiles = []
for c in accesor:
    temp = pygame.image.load('letter_'+c+'.png')
    tiles.append(pygame.transform.scale(temp, (100, 50)))
print(bg)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Character([10,570])
#player.rect.x = 10
#player.rect.y = 570
#all_sprites_list.add(player)
screen.blit(player.image,player.rect)
screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
def update_floor(i):
    for j in range(10):
        screen.blit(tiles[j],((((i+j)%10)*100),600))
pos = 0
update_floor(0)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
# Update the display
pygame.display.update()
# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:
    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    #update_floor(pos)
    #pos = pos + 1
    #all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(2)
# Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()
```

I referred to a  bunch of tutorial but it seems to be something very simple i am missing. Any help?

Comment: You have commented out the relevant code: `all_sprites_list.add(player)` and `all_sprites_list.draw(screen)`.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to solve the main issue. It was something very trivial thing that I was missing but i felt i shouldn't use a sprite group if i have only one sprite. So I was trying to do with without and it was getting confusing what to use and not to use.

Comment: If you have an additional question, you should make an additional post.

Comment: My bad. Will edit it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I remember I saw some tutorials that just didnt use Sprite class at all and then some that declared rectangle properties in the class while some outside the class in the main program. Must have gotten confused like that between them seeing different tutorials. I am trying to work with sprites on pygame for the first time so i might be having problems understanding it fully.

Comment: There is also the GroupSingle sprite group, which is made to offer Sprite Group functionality, but optimised for a single sprite. Ref: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.GroupSingle

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the relevant code: `all_sprites_list.add(player)` and `all_sprites_list.draw(screen)`. Uncomment the relevant code:

```py
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Character([10,570])
player.rect.x = 10
player.rect.y = 570
all_sprites_list.add(player)  

def update_floor(i):
    for j in range(10):
        screen.blit(tiles[j],((((i+j)%10)*100),600))

pos = 0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:
    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    update_floor(pos)
    pos = pos + 1
    
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(2)

# Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()
```